# Which point of the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ is closest to the point $(1,0)$?

Tags: calculus

This problem was assigned for an AP Calculus AB class and was not allowed a calculator:

Which point of the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ is closest to the point $(1,0)$?

We are not given answers and the teacher will be absent for $2$ weeks. I need to check my answer $(1/2,1/4)$ before she returns.

Here is my work:

$d=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-0)^2}$

$d=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+x}$

$d^2=(x-1)^2+x$

$2dd'=2(x-1)+1$

$d'=(2(x-1)+1)/(2d)$

$0=2(x-1)+1$

$x=1/2$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531154/finding-points-of-a-functions-graph-that-are-closest-to-a-given-point

Comment: The answer is $(1/4,1/2)$

Comment: @SauhardSharma What did I do wrong?

Comment: Seems good. But then the solution you obtain is $(1/2, \sqrt{2}/2)$.

Comment: @TarunPrakash You're right. The answer is indeed $(1/2,1/\sqrt{2})$. I made a small calculation error

Comment: @A.Pongrácz Oh yeah lol. Square root of 1/2 is 2/√2 not 1/4. **Facepalm.**

Comment: A shortcut : minimizing the distance is the same as minimizing the square of the distance.

Answer (score 2):

As a check:

Partial answer, completing the square.

$x,y\ge 0$.

$d^2= (x-1)^2+x= $

$x^2-2x+1+x= x^2-x+1;$

$d^2=(x-1/2)^2 -1/4+1 =$

$(x-1/2)^2 +3/4\ge 3/4$ (why?).

$d^2_{min} =3/4$, at $x=1/2$, $y=\sqrt{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

An algebra-free approach:
[image]

In order to draw the tangent from a point $P$ on a parabola, it is sufficient to project $P$ on the axis, reflect this point with respect to the vertex and join the new point with $P$. Since the tangent drawn from $P=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ is orthogonal to the line joining $P$ with $(1,0)$ (by Euclid's second theorem on right triangles, or just by computing slopes), $P$ is the wanted solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer is

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

(or you can use $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for the $y$-coordinate, they're the same.) Remember that you are looking for a point on the curve, and so need to substitute the $x$-value into the function describing that curve in order to get the corresponding $y$-coordinate, and here, that means taking the square root.

The corresponding minimizing distance is, of course, $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ units, or about 0.8660 (like $\sin 60^\circ$).

Answer (score 0):

We may look at differently:

Let the point we are after be $P:(x_0,\sqrt x_0)$. Now say we find the equation of the line, $l_1$, that passes through $P$ and $(1,0)$. Geometrically, $l_1$ is perpendicular to a tangent line to $y=\sqrt x$ that passes through $P$, hence its slope is $-\left(\frac1{2\sqrt x_0}\right)^{-1}$ and as such$$l_1:y=-2\sqrt x_0 (x-1).$$
Now noting that $l_1$ also passes though $P$ we have $$\sqrt x_0=-2\sqrt x_0 (x_0-1),$$which implies $x_0=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution point is such that the circle centered at $(1,0)$ tangents the curve, i.e. the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}(x-1)^2+y^2=r^2,\\y=\sqrt x\end{cases}$$ has a double root. By eliminating $y$,

$$(x-1)^2+x-r^2=0$$ has a double root when $$2(x-1)+1=0,$$ hence $$\left(\frac12,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right).$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $(x, \sqrt{x})$ a point on the graph. The distance to$(1,0)$ is then given by

$d(x)=((x-1)^2+\sqrt{x}^2)^{1/2}=((x-1)^2+x)^{1/2}$.

Let $f(x):=d(x)^2.$

It is now your turn to determine $x_0 \ge 0$ such that $f(x_0)= \min\{f(x): x \ge 0 \}.$

(we get $x_0 =1/2$).

We then have $d(x_0)= \min\{d(x): x \ge 0 \}.$

Comment: Maybe you overlooked the editing of the post. The author provided a complete solution.